# creating some test data and for 80% of the rows in Batch, I want to make a corresponding row in Uploads with Ingested = Y

Tags: plsql

I am creating some test data and for 80% of the rows in Batch, I want to make a corresponding row in Uploads with Ingested = Y. For the rest of the data I would like ingested as 'N'. I have the main portion of the loop working but am unsure how to run it so 80% runs with Y and 20% runs with N

```
insert into uploads (id, id_batch, file_name, upload_date, ingested)
select rownum+4000 as id,id as id_batch,'Batch' || batch.start_date || ' ' || rownum as file_name ,batch.start_date,'Y' as ingested from batch
cross join lateral (select level from dual
where  batch.id = batch.id 
connect by level <= dbms_random.value(50,250)
)
```

Would I need case statements for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to insert all data using a single insert statement. The statement can set 20% of the rows to have ingested='N' and 80% to have ingested='Y'. This can be done using either [MOD](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MOD.html) or [NTILE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NTILE.html) to create 5 buckets. Then, DECODE can be used to put 'N' into 1 of the 5 buckets and 'Y' into the other 4 buckets.

```
SELECT ROWNUM + 4000 AS id
      ,id       AS id_batch
      ,'Batch'
       || b.start_date
       || ' '
       || ROWNUM     AS file_name
      ,b.start_date
      ,DECODE(MOD(ROWNUM,5), 0, 'N', 'Y') every_fifth_row_is_n
      ,DECODE(NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY dbms_random.value(1,100)), 1, 'N', 'Y') random_fifth_of_rows_is_n
      ,DECODE(NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY ROWNUM), 3, 'N', 'Y') third_fifth_of_rows_is_n
  FROM batch b
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT level
                      FROM   dual
                      WHERE  b.id = b.id CONNECT BY
                      level <= dbms_random.value(50,250)
                    )
ORDER BY id
```